# Append strings to array with Immutable

Tags: scala, mutable, immutablearray

Having as Input a list of String (one of them could be `None`). How can I return a Array of String using `Immutable Object`.

It's pretty easy if I use `var` or `Mutable Object`, here an example:

```
def getArrayString(string: String, list1: List[String], list2: Option[List[String]]): Array[String] = {
  var ret = Array[String]()
  ret = ret :+ string
  if (list1.nonEmpty) {
    for (item <- list1) {
      ret = ret :+ item
    }
  }
  if (list2.isDefined) {
    for (item <- list2.get) {
      ret = ret :+ item
    }
  }
  ret
}
```

***Question1***:
What if I want to use just `val` object?

N.B.: if `list2` is `None` the returning array should not have any `None` Object

***Question2***:
..and if `list1` and `list2` were `List[CustomClass]` where `CustomClass` is

`case class CustomClass(string:String)`

How would you do?

***Question3***:
...What if we complicate the method with...

`case class CustomClass1(string1:String)`

`case class CustomClass2(string2:String)`

obviously CustomClass1 and CustomClass2 might have some other parameters in their class that make them different from each other. The signature of the method would be then:

```
def getArrayString( string: String
                , list1: List[CustomClass1]
                , list2: Option[List[CustomClass2]]
              ): Array[String]`
```

Comment: (string :: list1 ::: list2.getOrElse(Nil)).toArray

Comment: If `CustomClass` is the same for both lists, you can map it just once at the end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `::` which will prepend an element to a list, and `++` which will concatenate 2 lists:

```
val ret = (string :: (list1 ++ list2.getOrElse(Nil))).toArray
```

For the updated version:

```
val ret = (string :: (list1 ++ list2.getOrElse(Nil)).map(_.string)).toArray
```

Comment: In a hurry to answer first you got a compilation error :) Move brackets to include string variable.

Comment: @tkachuko Updated

Comment: Nitpick: mixing `::` and `++` seems a bit weird to me — I would either use `::` and `:::`, or `+:` and `++`. One is the `List` API, the other is the `Seq` API (which also works for `List`s).

Comment: @SethTisue, why is it weird? is it inefficient?

Comment: The differently-named methods do the same thing, there's no efficiency difference. It's no big deal, it just reads a bit oddly to me to mix and match the two APIs.

Answer (score 1):

Every time I see `Option` I think "fold?".

```
def getArrayString( string: String
                  , list1: List[String]
                  , list2: Option[List[String]]
                  ): Array[String] =
  list2.foldLeft(string +: list1)(_++_).toArray
```

**update** (as requested)

```
case class CustomClass(string:String)
def getArrayString( string: String
                    , list1: List[CustomClass]
                    , list2: Option[List[CustomClass]]
                  ): Array[String] =
  string +: list2.foldLeft(list1)(_++_).map(_.string).toArray
```

Or the slightly more concise:

```
  Array(string) ++ (list1 /: list2)(_++_).map(_.string)
```

Comment: Thank you jwvh, but this doesn't work if `list2` is `None` and it is less readable than Alvaro's answer

Comment: Really? What should be returned if `list2` is `None`?

Comment: It has to return an Array of String.. 
EDIT: I did some testing and yes. Your code return what it should :)

Comment: I edited the question, could you extend your answer please?

Comment: Thank you, really appreciate it! ... but if `CustomClass` (say `CustomClass1` and `CustomClass2`, respectively for `list1` and `list2`) is not the same for both lists, this would not work though

Comment: `Array(string) ++ (list1.map(_.string) /: list2.map(_.map(_.string)))(_++_)` with this should work. But it is a little bit obscure to read...

Comment: @salvob, I don't quite understand your question and I don't see any situation where your rather verbose solution would hold any advantage over the more concise options I have posted.

Comment: `case class CustomClass1(string:String)`
`case class CustomClass2(string:String)`

`def getArrayString( string: String
                    , list1: List[CustomClass1]
                    , list2: Option[List[CustomClass2]]
                  ): Array[String]`

Comment: Ah, I see. Yes, your solution will work in that case, however I think I'd prefer it like this: `Array(string) ++ list1.map(_.string) ++ list2.getOrElse(Nil).map(_.string)`. But the _real_ solution is to pull the common attributes into a `trait`, then not only can you return to the simpler `getArrayString()` code I've proposed, it will also be able to process the inputs in either order: `List[Custom1], Option[List[Custom2]]` or vise versa.